# Timing issue with file input/read

Tags: javascript

I'm working a Javascript function called on a web page.  The intent is to open a file dialog and then read the file.  When I use the debugger to step through the application it works correctly.  However, when executing the code without the debugger I don't get either of the alerts.  I'm suspecting it is a timing issue where I trigger the click but then try to process the file before it is selected.  Do I need some type of on-click handler to wait until the file select is finished processing?

Here's a minimal version of the function.

```
   function importHistory() { 
            var input = $(document.createElement('input')); 
            input.attr("type", "file"); 
            input.trigger('click'); 

            var reader = new FileReader(); 
            reader.onload = function() { 
                var text = reader.result; 
                alert(text); 
            }; 

            reader.onerror = function(event) { 
                alert(event.target.error.code); 
            } 

            reader.readAsText(input[0].files[0]); 
        };
```

Comment: The entire `reader` code needs to be moved inside the handler function for the input's `onchange` event (which doesn't exist yet).

Comment: In my experience, I have rather called functions from constructor or printed messages for debugging.  Is it possible the "input" object is not yet created, since the page is just opening? (which explains why it would work while debugging)  Try logging some info, like console.log(inupt) right after you assign it.  Make sure the object exists.  Same thing for reader object.

Comment: Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/p1g7swch/ (I've also used jQuery where possible)

Comment: @ChrisG - Thanks, that works for me.  If you would like to put it in an answer i'll accept it.